# Unique visitors in cloudflare

Tags: cloudflare

What is difference between total unique visitors vs maximum unique visitors? Why is maximum unique visitors less than total unique visitors?
For example, in report of cloudflare of my site, total unique visitors value is 300, maximum unique visitors value is only 55.

Answer (score -1):

- Total unique visitors 
  This is the overall number of unique visitors for the whole month. So, you had 300 visitors in total that month.
- Maximum unique visitors is the most visitors you had in one day during that month. So, on your best day that month you had 55 people visit.
- Minimum unique visitors is the smallest number of visitors you had in one day during that month.

To learn more about Cloudflare analytics, have a look at their blog post about it https://blog.cloudflare.com/introducing-partner-analytics/

Comment: Absolutely wrong. Just look example on their blog. As you said, 28*min<=total<=31*max, in example total~70millions, max~6millions, min~3.5millioms. So, 28*3.5<=70<=30*6? It's not true.

Comment: In dashboard, they wrote: total unique visitors (last 24 hours), max unique visitors (last 24 hours), min unique visitors (last 24 hours).

Comment: It depends on the view you're in. In my case, I was looking at the month view rather than last 24 hours. In your case, it would be 300 unique visitors in the last 24 hours and 55 visitors in your busiest hour.

Comment: Thank you. I am sure you are right or wrong. I am just confused :(